# SEO Lite Parse Error

Tags: seo-lite

I'm getting the following parse error when I click to view the SEO Lite settings in the control panel:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /nfs/c11/h01/mnt/196778/domains/hallettperrin.thedesigncore.com/html/engine/user/addons/seo_lite/views/index.php on line 19

EE v3.4.2
Seo Lite v1.5.3

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was a compatibility issue with PHP 5.3 and has been fixed in SEO Lite 1.5.4 - please download it here: https://github.com/bjornbjorn/SEO-Lite